# How to express a risk of breaking a target/objective

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

I am French, and I am looking for ideally a word or a short expression to express the situation where someone is about to do something that is going to put at danger/risk a goal/target. Let's say someone is stopping smoking. What do you call the moment he fights against himself not to take a cigarette. Or someone who is making a diet and is fighting not to take that delicious pizza... I'm sure you get the idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first phrase that occurs to me for the person's emotional state is **internal conflict**.

The overall situation might be called a **test of willpower**.

Comment: Thks for the help chaos. Sounds good as well...

Comment: I really like the willpower term. That suits actually what I am seeking. Short and precise:) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

You might call it *[the moment of truth](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/moment+of+truth)*:

> a moment when a person or thing is put to the test

Comment: Ooh, wish I'd thought of that!  It's even right there in the question, *"What do you call the moment..."*

Comment: Thnak you ninja dude... Nevertheless moment of truth is to my understanding something that happens once. It is a once think moment. Whereas what I am trying to express can happen regularly...

Comment: Moments of truth can happen regularly, though I agree the term sounds more momentous than an everyday struggle.

Comment: Every time you want a cigarette after quitting, it's a new moment of truth.

Comment: @Marc you are most welcome.  Your [snowflake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon) rocks!

Answer (score 3):

I'd call such a moment **inner turmoil**.  Instead of *turmoil*, you could also use **struggle** or **conflict**.  I also like chaos's **internal**.

Comment: Hello Daniel. thanks for editing and answering. Do you only call is that way or is it a "popular/common" expression?

Comment: I've heard it frequently enough to suggest it as useful.

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel for the help... I think nevertheless I will go with the term willpower. Your inputs nevertheless brought new words to my vocabulary. So a big thank you anyway:)

Comment: @Marc: *Willpower* is the quality being tested by someone who has *resolved* [not] to do something, when faced with *temptation*. If you're happy with **willpower**, you might like to edit your question text, since at the moment it seems to be asking for words to describe *wavering* at a moment of extreme *temptation*, rather than the quality shown by someone who *resists* the urge to *give in*.

Comment: Thank you very much FumbleFinger for the more than interesting input:)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think the OP's use of the term *willpower* in the above comment is short for *test of willpower*, suggested by chaos.  OP is referring to the fact that he has accepted chaos' answer.

Comment: @Daniel: Point taken, but I do think we're more likely to say we *resist, triumph over* or *give in, yield* to [a moment of] ***temptation*** than to a *test of willpower*. For my money, *temptation* fits better when the focus is on a person's wavering frame of mind. To me, *test of willpower* tends to imply successful resistance, rather than wavering with the possibility of succumbing.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure turmoil or willpower or internal apply very well to the general case.
This statement equally fits the question: "This bridge won't be open in time for Bastille day if we don't appropriate more funds by close of business today".

`Today`, in the above example, is *do or die*. It's *make or break*. It's a *deadline* and the engineering is giving the committee an *ultimatum*.  All of these phrases apply to the situation. I'm not sure what the impact of your phrase is intended to have, but I think *make or break* fits very well, though it's colloquial.

Comment: I believe that "ultimatum" is usually used when the person is making a threat. It's not appropriate when they're warning about a natural consequence of doing (or failing to do) something.

Answer (score 2):

I believe **temptation**, suggested by FumbleFingers [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74473/how-to-express-a-risk-of-breaking-a-target-objective/74474#comment144451_74474), deserves its own answer.  Your protagonist is *tempted* to take the cigarette or the pizza, making the situation one of *temptation*.

Answer (score 0):

In Catholic doctrine, a circumstance that puts one at risk of doing something wrong is called an "occasion of sin".  The attractive acquantance who offers the abstainer a smoke, drink, sex, etc. is establishing that occasion of sin, which is, of course, to be assiduously avoided.

Comment: Pizza isn't a sin, but I agree that this doctrinal phrase could be applied in a humorous way.  (I'd probably avoid this option, though, when conversing with non-native speakers, unless I was ready to provide a long explanation...)

Comment: Ah, but pizza could be a sin (no doubt venial, rather than mortal) if you had taken a vow of abstinence or the pizza belonged to someone else.